# Spockframework soft assertion describes only first fail

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

Spockframework offers soft assertions mechanism, but it seems it doesn't work properly (at least in my configuration).

I have created simplest test:

```
verifyAll {
    1 == 2
    2 == 3
}
```

I expect to see two failure message, but I see only first one:

```
Condition not satisfied:

1 == 2
  |
  false
```

Second one is also executed, but it appears only in gradle report:

```
org.example.SoftAssertionsTest > simplest test FAILED
    org.spockframework.runtime.SpockComparisonFailure at SoftAssertionsTest.groovy:9
    org.spockframework.runtime.SpockComparisonFailure at SoftAssertionsTest.groovy:10
```

Versions:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.+")
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.3-groovy-2.5')
```

I have pushed this example to: https://github.com/fergus-macdubh/spock-soft-assertions

**Is there a way to make it show ALL messages?**

Comment: I'd be very surprised, if spock would continue after the first error. What is your usecase for _not_ failing fast? If you want to see many things fail fast for the same test, then have a look at the tables and the @Unroll features.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, for me `verifyAll` works as expected. When cloning your Gradle project, I cannot build anything, seems like the build file is incomplete and defines no targets. I am a Maven person, so I cannot help to fix your Gradle build.

Comment: @cfrick, with `verifyAll` Spock will indeed continue and evaluate all conditions. This is the [very purpose of `verifyAll`](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_using_code_verifyall_code_to_assert_multiple_expectations_together).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I saw similar behaviour with an old 4.4.1 Gradle version installed locally. But as soon as I added `gradlew[.bat]` files to your project and modified your build file to be more similar to the [Spock example project](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/spock-1.x/build.gradle), it worked.

```groovy
apply plugin: "groovy"

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = "Soft Assertions"

// Spock works with Java 1.8 and above
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
  compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8"
  testCompile platform("org.spockframework:spock-bom:2.0-M1-groovy-2.5")
  testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core"
  testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-junit4" // you can remove this if your code does not rely on old JUnit 4 rules

  // optional dependencies for using Spock
  testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3" // only necessary if Hamcrest matchers are used
  testRuntime "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.3"          // allows mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces)
  testRuntime "org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6"    // allows mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB)

  // dependencies used by examples in this project
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.+")
  testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.3-groovy-2.5')
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The console log now looks as expected:

```
Testing started at 12:57 ...

> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
(...)
> Task :test

Multiple Failures (2 failures)
    org.spockframework.runtime.SpockComparisonFailure: Condition not satisfied:

1 == 2
  |
  false

    org.spockframework.runtime.SpockComparisonFailure: Condition not satisfied:

2 == 3
  |
  false

(...)
```

Comment: Hi @kriegaex,

It works in provided config, thank you!
Is this `useJUnitPlatform()` mandatory with spock 2.0? I've noticed that it always can't find any tests when I upgrade spock version to 2 (also that `useJUnitPlatform()` didn't help in real project, it still couldn't find any test).

Comment: Your sample project is Spock 1. BTW, Spock 1 and 2 are different insofar as Spock 1 is based on JUnit 4 and Spock 2 on JUnit 5. Rather use the master branch of the project I linked to than the Spock 1.x branch if you need sample code. There also is my pending [pull request](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/pull/35) upgrading everything to the latest Spock 2 milestone, it just has not been merged yet. I recommend to use it instead of the current master. The sample project contains both Maven and Gradle builds, BTW. I always use Maven, Gradle is not my thing at all.